# How would I query a User timeline in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

I am testing Firestore to substitute parts of our relational system. Assume a simple twitter-like structure where users can follow other users:

```
users/{userID}
  -- userInfo 

relationships/{followerID_followedID}
  -- followerId (string)
  -- followedId (string)
  -- createdAt  (timestamp)

posts/{postID}
  -- userId 
  -- createdAt  (timestamp)
  -- payload
```

I don't know how would I query (or model / denormalize the data to be able to query) the aggregated posts from the users I follow.

For example, these are the users I follow:

```
 db.collection("relationships")
     .whereEquals("followerId", ME)
```

And these the latest posts for today

```
 db.collection("posts")
     .whereGreaterThan("createdAt", now-24h)
```

I understand I can't unfortunately make a cross-collection query to get the posts for today Of the users I follow.

I'm after some advice on how to model the posts/ collection, its indexes or data duplication so I can make these kinds of queries efficiently

I've seen an example based on the older Firebase database that updates all followers timelines on every post:

```
          self._mainUser.child("followers").once("value", function(followerList) {
            followerList.forEach(function(follower) {
                if (!follower.val()) {
                    return;
                }
                var childRef = db.collection("users")
                    .document(follower.name());

                childRef.collection("feed").document(sparkRefId).set(true);
            });
          });
```

Is this kind of solution really the only way to go? I mean, in the case of a user with 100,000+ followers to update 100,000 documents? Because instead of totally ditching my SQL backend (that I was hoping to) maybe it's interesting to keep a minimal SQL to run these kind of queries and save a lot of computing and storage.

Comment: This looks exactly the same as your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49353388/followers-on-firestore-retrieve-user-timeline

Comment: argh! double post! thanks